# I'm trying to change the type of vertices on my mesh

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, import, vertices

I Imported a mesh into 2.8 and for some reason the vertices/faces are in a triangular fashion and when I try to grab a vertex or multiple to move them, it doesn't pull the faces/vertices around it with it. See attached pictures below. I just want to know how to make the vertices behave like your average mesh so I can edit it properly. If you couldn't tell I am new to blender but so far loving the experience.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgu)

[image]r.com/nARcw.jpg

Comment: you need to fix the topology (manually, fixing the empty spaces and merge close vertexes or in some automatic way like remesh)

Comment: In Edit mode, select all of the vertices, then Mesh menu > Merge > By Distance. This will merge all the vertices that occupy the same position in 3D space back together again, (connecting the tris together). Next to change the triangles to quads: Select all the vertices, then Face menu > Tris to Quads.

Comment: You could use multiple tools to fix this horrible topology, eg edge dissolve, convert tris to quads, apart what said above .